# Android FCM not able to start Service and receive resposne

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Android FCM and have so far setup all, getting default notifications when I send from firebase but the Service is not handling the sent messages.

Below is my service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]



@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // Not getting messages here? See why this may be:
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
            scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

I have declared this service in Manifest file also.

When I send the message from Firebase Console, I do receive default notifications with title and body but nothing on the Debug Log. In fact the service is not even triggered. I need to implement image notifications and key value pair so this is required.
Below is Manifest declaration:

```
  <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Below is the declaration in Application Class.

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Subscribed";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Message";
                        }
                        Log.d("Token", msg);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this service is only called if your app is in the foreground. If it's in the background, the default handler takes care of it. Not sure there's a way to override that behavior except by sending a "data" notification instead of a text one.

Comment: You are right, the service is called when App is in foreground.